# Should I check for compile errors only after attaching the shaders and linking?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

When I do it the other way around I get compile error, which is essentially empty, getting some strange characters.
It's in a class so I don't know which part of the code one needs to see for this.
But after compiling the shaders, I do this in the constructor

```
glAttachShader(m_ID, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(m_ID, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(m_ID);
checkForErrors(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
```

and that works but this:

```
glAttachShader(m_ID, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(m_ID, fragmentShader);
checkForErrors(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(m_ID);
```

(Notive that checkForErrors is now called before glLinkProgram) This isn't working...
which is strange because when stepping through the program
I use
`glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);`
and I see that length gets a value of zero after this gets called
and yet
`glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &res);`
sets res to 0 indicating an error...
Then even if didn't use _malloca for the infoLog array but allocated on the stack with a fixed size like 500 then I get a longer string but again filled with strange characters...

Anyway, the checkForErrors function is overloaded so it's like this:

```
{
    checkForErrors(ShaderType::vertex, vertexShader);
    checkForErrors(ShaderType::fragment, fragmentShader);
    //checkForErrors(ShaderType::program, m_ID);
}
```

I commented out the last part because I am trying to force a link error and see what `glValidateProgram(m_ID);`
will do. So here's the most probable function where the error happens:

***Since I ended up changing it a bit the updated version is like this:

```
void Shader::checkForErrors(ShaderType type, U32 shader)
{
    const char* typeStr{ getTypeStr(type) };
    int length, res;
    if (type != ShaderType::program)
    {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &res);
        if (!res)
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
            //char* infoLog{ (char*)_malloca(length) };
            char infoLog[500];
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, length, &length, infoLog);
            std::cout << typeStr << " shader failed to compile:\n" << infoLog << '\n';
            std::abort();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &res);
        if (!res)
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
            //char* infoLog((char*)_malloca(length));
            char infoLog[500];
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, length, &length, infoLog);
            std::cout << typeStr << " shader failed to link:\n" << infoLog << '\n';
            std::abort();
        }
    }
}
```

But the previous problems remain, it's just that first we see that there's a compilation error and then inside the if block we get the length of that to be 0 and then of course I get these strange characters because there's nothing to be written to infoLog...
This is what it was before which I will keep in order for what I am saying to make sense.
Maybe I should just delete the above and re-write it but it's pretty much the same behavior and seems like a small change than the old version which since that happened I think I should also include:

```
void Shader::checkForErrors(ShaderType type, U32 shader)
{
    const char* typeStr{ getTypeStr(type) };
    int length, res;
    if (type != ShaderType::program)
    {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

        //char* infoLog{ (char*)_malloca(length) };
        char infoLog[500];
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &res);
        if (!res)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, length, &length, infoLog);
            std::cout << typeStr << " shader failed to compile:\n" << infoLog << '\n';
            std::abort();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* infoLog((char*)_malloca(length));
        glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &res);
        if (!res)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, length, &length, infoLog);
            std::cout << typeStr << " shader failed to link:\n" << infoLog << '\n';
            std::abort();
        }
    }
}
```

typeStr is just vertex, fragment or program according to the type which is just an unsigned int enum.

Later on after I have written it, I realized that it's better to move the glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length); and infoLog inside the if(!res) block but even so and even without using _malloca I get the same error which is just strange characters instead of explaining the error... But if I reorder it, again it works and I get a triangle on the screen...

So I wonder what I messed up...
Here's what I tried:
Instead of getting the strings in the stringstream by const reference I copied them to const std::string and that had no effect(see below the constructor for Shader)
I even tried with an int enum so it's not that either(in Shader.h included below)
Not using _malloca had no effect, the small reordering which can be seen by the "updated" version of the function, moving checkForErrors before attaching the shaders, using an int enum instead of U32(which is unsigned int). Making sure that res should be 0 when an error occurs by googling and intentionally breaking the vertex shader and breaking the vertex shader while leaving the "wrong" order that causes the error.
I still get the strange error instead of the one that should tell me about the vertex shader. All of that makes sense if I need to first link the program and then check for compile errors in the shaders but I think I remember doing the exact same think in the past...
Anyway, I guess I am mistaken? Then how do I cause a link error on purpose?
I tried deleting glLinkProgram and instead of a link error I got this strange one.

So just in case the whole of the class is needed, here's the cpp file for it:

```
#include "Shader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "ASSERT.h"
Shader::Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath)
    : m_ID{ glCreateProgram() }
{
    std::ifstream vertex{ vertexPath };
    std::ifstream fragment{ fragmentPath };
    std::stringstream vertexStream;
    std::stringstream fragmentStream;

    ASSERT(vertex, "Couldn't open vertexShader file");
    ASSERT(fragment, "Couldn't open fragmentShader file");

    vertexStream << vertex.rdbuf();
    fragmentStream << fragment.rdbuf();

    //std::cout << "\nVertex shader:\n" << vertexStream.str() << "\n\n\n"
    //  << "Fragment shader:\n" << fragmentStream.str() << "\n\n\n";

    /*const std::string& vertexStr{ vertexStream.str() };
    const std::string& fragmentStr{ fragmentStream.str() };*/

    const std::string& vertexStr{ vertexStream.str() };
    const std::string& fragmentStr{ fragmentStream.str() };
    const char* vSrc{ vertexStr.c_str()};
    const char* fSrc{ fragmentStr.c_str()};

    U32 vertexShader = compile(ShaderType::vertex, vSrc);
    U32 fragmentShader = compile(ShaderType::fragment, fSrc);

    glAttachShader(m_ID, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(m_ID, fragmentShader);
    checkForErrors(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    //glLinkProgram(m_ID);
    //glValidateProgram(m_ID);
    
}

void Shader::checkForErrors(U32 vertexShader, U32 fragmentShader)
{
    checkForErrors(ShaderType::vertex, vertexShader);
    checkForErrors(ShaderType::fragment, fragmentShader);
    //checkForErrors(ShaderType::program, m_ID);
}

U32 Shader::compile(ShaderType type, const char* source)
{
    U32 shader = glCreateShader(int(type));
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, nullptr);
    glCompileShader((int)type);
    //glAttachShader(m_ID, shader);
    return shader;
}

const char* Shader::getTypeStr(ShaderType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case ShaderType::program: return "program"; 
    case ShaderType::vertex: return "vertex"; 
    case ShaderType::fragment: return "fragment"; 
    default:
        ASSERT(false, "ShaderType enum of unknown type, should be program, vertex or fragment");
        return "noShader";
    }
    //return "noShader";
}

void Shader::checkForErrors(ShaderType type, U32 shader)
{
    const char* typeStr{ getTypeStr(type) };
    int length, res;
    if (type != ShaderType::program)
    {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &res);
        if (!res)
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
            //char* infoLog{ (char*)_malloca(length) };
            char infoLog[500];
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, length, &length, infoLog);
            std::cout << typeStr << " shader failed to compile:\n" << infoLog << '\n';
            std::abort();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &res);
        if (!res)
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
            //char* infoLog((char*)_malloca(length));
            char infoLog[500];
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, length, &length, infoLog);
            std::cout << typeStr << " shader failed to link:\n" << infoLog << '\n';
            std::abort();
        }
    }
}

void Shader::bind()
{
    glUseProgram(m_ID);
}

void Shader::unBind()
{
    glUseProgram(0);
}

void Shader::Delete(U32 vs, U32 fs)
{
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);
}
```

Update #1:
As BDL noticed, I was trying to compile a shader type instead of a shader...
I think I fixed that but I still get the same error somehow...
I really don't understand why it would work at all, I just tried and with the "correct" order it works even if I comment out glCompileShader which is very strange to me... I guess glLinkProgram also compiles them? But I don't understand why the suggested fix doesn't work.
I changed the compile function like this:

```
U32 Shader::compile(ShaderType type, const char* source)
{
    U32 shader = glCreateShader(int(type));
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader); //<-- this was: glCompileShader(int(type));
    //glAttachShader(m_ID, shader);
    return shader;
}
```

the glAttachShader is called in the constructor just to allow me to control the order of execution and I am thinking about adding it in the compile function... So that's why it's commented out here.
Maybe I am doing something wrong with the enum?
Here's the shader.h class which I think I didn't include last time:

```
#include "types.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>

class Shader
{
    enum class ShaderType : int;
public:
    Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath);
    void bind();
    void unBind();
private:
    void Delete(U32 vs, U32 fs);
    const char* getTypeStr(ShaderType type);
    void checkForErrors(ShaderType type, U32 shader);
    void checkForErrors(U32 vertexShader, U32 fragmentShader);
    U32 compile(ShaderType type, const char* source);

private:
    enum class ShaderType : int
    {
        vertex = GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
        fragment = GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
        program = 0
    };
private:
    U32 m_ID;
};
```

Update #2:
I think I was just using
`glCompileShader(int(type));` instead of `glCompileShader(shader);` and I think that's all...
I was getting a compile error because of that and I thought I was getting the same error after the fix but somehow I missed that it was about link error(I called checkForErrors before linking the program and checkForErrors was handling link errors too...)

However, I am still very confused about how it could possibly work when I didn't run `glCompileShader(shader)` at all... I had that commented out and somehow it worked if I was doing the checks after linking. I thought this was impossible, my best guess would be that glLinkProgram can sometimes work with shaders attached but not compiled.
Once again many thanks to DBL for spotting the error!

Comment: glCompileShader takes the shader object as argument, not the shader type. Are you checking for OpenGL errors with glGetError?

Comment: No such error checking at the moment... You are right, what on earth was I doing there...
But how does it work if I reorder it, should it not work at all since the shaders wouldn't get compiled? Mysteriously I still get the same error even after fixing the mistake...
I will update the post maybe I didn't fix it completely?

Comment: Without seeing how you use the shader class, I'm not sure if I can help you any further. I noticed that `res` isn't manually initialized, so whenever `glGetShaderiv` fails, the value will be 0 (default).

Comment: I just updated the post and added shader.h and I think I have added shader.cpp previously so maybe now you can see how I use the shader class. If not what should I do?

Comment: I am very sorry I think it's working now, it's just that I wasn't careful and I added checking for link errors so now if I check before linking it's not working because I hadn't yet called GL_LINK_PROGRAM. I thought I was getting the same error but it looks like it was just the link error now not the vertex shader. Many thanks!

Comment: *"Should I check for compile errors only after attaching the shaders and linking?"* - Yes, sure!